# User popup window before Prism 7.1 window is loaded - how?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-7

I'm using Prism 7.1 WPF and Prism Unity.

Before the main `<prism:PrismApplication/>` runs, or when the main Prism window appears, I want to have a modal pop-up window for user to input some data.
The input data would be for user login, and, more importantly, to *determine which Prism modules to load into the application.*

How would I go about doing this? I have tried to display a custom WPF window in the following `PrismApplication` overload methods, but either the window doesn't appear, or the entire application closes:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return base.CreateModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

}
```

For example, if I put in a call to display a custom WPF window in the CreateModuleCatalog(), it will show, however the entire application closes:

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        if (loginWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // OK
        }
        else
        {
            // Cancel
        }

        return base.CreateModuleCatalog();
    }
```

... and if I put the call in OnStartup(), it won't show until *all* the other overrides are executed and the main Prism window is displayed (which is too late to process the user's input):

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        if (loginWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // OK
        }
        else
        {
            // Cancel
        }
    }
```

I've played around with the different methods, changed the position of the calls to the base class's method etc, but can't seem to get it working. Can anyone suggest how this can be done?
The reason for this is that I don't want to load entire modules into the application if I don't need to (based upon the user input).
Thanks....

Comment: Try to show the login window using the `ShowDialog()` method in the `InitializeShell` method of the bootstrapper.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. While you are able to put the `ShowDialog()` method in `InitialiseShell`, the other bootstrapper methods seem to fire prior to the Window being displayed no-matter-what. Thus, irrespective of whether I click OK or Cancel, the `CreateModuleCatalog()` method fires, thus I cannot conditionally load modules at run time. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

‍♀️ Zombie answer, but better late that never...

I'm not sure that this is the preferred way to do things, but I do this same thing in `CreateShell()`:

```
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        // Stop things from shutting down when the dialog closes
        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        var loginView = Container.Resolve<LoginView>();

        loginView.ShowDialog();

        // ...Do something with the result of the login dialog here...

        var mainWindow = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Loaded += ( _, __ ) =>
        {
            Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
            mainWindow.Activate();
        };
        return mainWindow;
    }
```